# AEM Mocks: Problem with ResourceResolverType.JCR_OAK

Tags: mocking, aem, aem-6

I am using AEM Mocks (with JUnit 5). I create my context as follows:

`private final AemContext aemContext = new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_OAK);`

Note the use of `JCR_OAK`. Everything works fine if I try to use `JCR_MOCK` instead. When trying to inject certain services, I get the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize JCR_OAK resource resolver factory: Unable to invoke method 'activate' for class org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryActivator`

I already tried the advice described here - inverting the `sling-mock-oak` and `uber-jar` dependencies - but this can't be done. If `sling-mock-oak` comes before the `uber-jar`, other errors are thrown.

https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/unable-to-initialize-jcr-oak-resource-resolver-factory/td-p/319688

Below is a partial list of dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${junitVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.wcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.junit5</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.wcm.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>io.wcm.maven.aem-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.8.0002</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.logging-mock</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver-mock</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.24</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock-oak</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10-1.16.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please tell me why I get the error above?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution?

Comment: Nope. None yet.

Comment: I did -> https://wcm-io.atlassian.net/browse/WTES-61

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my node property request's working by switching to **ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK** instead, and correcting my test decencies to match the pom.xml in the example https://github.com/adobe/aem-guides-wknd